# Set properties not included in Json during Jackson deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am using Jackson to deserialize Json strings that look something like this.

**JSON Strings:**

```
{
   "ids": [123, 456, 789],
   "filters": ["abcFilter", "xyzFilter"],
   {
      ...(nested objects)
   }
}
```

**Target object class:**

```
class Target {
   int[] ids;
   String[] filters;
   NestedTarget nested;
}
```

**NestedTarget:**

```
class NestedTarget {
   boolean multiple;
   NestedTarget[] nested;
   ...
}
```

The `multiple` field in all the nested objects is not part of the Json, but I want to set it based on the condition `ids.length > 0 || filter.length > 0`. There could be many levels of nested objects (dozens), so ideally I would like to do this during the deserialization process. I have explored using Jackson annotations like `@JsonSerialize` and `@JacksonInject`, but none of them seem to do the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: In your Target class, you declare `ids` as type `int[]`. I believe in your JSON you should not be wrapping the id values with `"`, representing strings. Try removing the double quotes from the values: `[123, 456, 789]`

Comment: Why is `multiple` on the NestedTarget level? If it depends on `ids` and `filters`, then it should be in Target level, isn't it? And then you can make it a calculate property by declaring `isMultiple` function, the overhead of calculating `ids.length > 0 || filter.length > 0` should be negligible.

Comment: @pczeus You are correct...that is just a typo which I will fix

Comment: @S.D. The issue here is that the nested classes don't have a pointer to their parent, so they can't access the `multiple` field from the parent. Also, there are multiple levels of nesting.